# App Store Rejection With Reason: your app requires users to register personal information to purchase non account-based in-app purchase products

Tags: app-store, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

For last few days this cat and mouse game is going on between me and App Store Reviewers. And despite searching everywhere, I have not been able to find an answer to this question, so seeking help here.

I have submitted an app with **auto-renewable subscriptions** in it.

My app requires that users sign-in in order to see additional options, which includes subscription option as well.

App Store Reviewers keep rejecting my app citing this same text every time:

> Regarding 5.1.1, we continue to notice that your app requires users to register with personal information to purchase non account-based in-app purchase products, which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> To resolve this issue, it would be appropriate to make it clear to the user that registering will enable them to access the content from any of their iOS devices and provide them a way to register at any time, if they wish to later extend access to additional iOS devices.
>
> We look forward to reviewing your resubmitted app.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

What is `non account-based in-app purchase products` by the way?

I have also made it clear in my app what App Reviewer have asked above, i.e. make clear to the users that registering will enable them to access the content from any of their iOS devices. I didn't say `iOS devices` specifically, but said `other devices` since I'll have the same app on Android devices as well.

While I appreciate App Store Reviewers to help me improve my app, but I am totally lost here. I have submitted two updates to my app but every time it got rejected with the same reason.

Over this period I have also read their guidelines, read many similar cases online, but am still not clear what is required of me here.

Do they want the users to be able to purchase subscriptions even if they are not signed in? If so then technically how does this work? First it'll break the core functionality of the app since without registration I don't have user's info to create an account for them. Secondly how will I know which user purchased the subscription? I have to tie the subscription to the user's account on my backend. This means first I need to create an account for the user before user can purchase a subscription.

Please help me to get this right.

Currently I am waiting App Store's reply and my screens looks like these, with all other options removed when not signed in, and added text bottom of the Sign-In option, and help icon on top right of the screen where there is more information available for the user; and the one when user is signed-in.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app was eventually approved last year. The change I made was to remove the Subscriptions button from the Settings menu. And move it inside the user profile page. This means that user can see the Subscription option only after signing in and by going to their profile page. While this doesn't make sense to me, but that's how probably Apple wanted it. Subsequent updates to my app were also approved without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I would be a user of your app, I think I would find this behavior quite odd.

I would expect a login/registration screen when starting your app. If I decide to create an account, the Subscription button would always be visible within the settings.

However, there would also be an option "Continue without registration". If you do not create an account, the settings page could show some info text like "Some features are only available for registered members. Please tap here to create an account". Tapping the corresponding cell would show the registration page that is also shown when starting your app for the first time.

Maybe some users created an account in the past but forgot their passwort? Then they would not be able to restore their purchases, right?

Your login/registration form should also contain a "Forgot Password" option.

Comment: In the original version of the app this is exactly how it was. The subscription button was always visible. Clicking on it told the user that they needed to create an account first. Apple approved that version. Then I updated the version with some other changes, and Apple caught me on this subscription issue, which they themselves had approved in the previous version.

Comment: Sometimes things just slip, but now that I am thinking about it...always display this button. The Apple(!) account that was used to purchase the subscription is not necessarily the same as the account address that was used to sign in to your app.

Comment: That's right, and that's why I need the user to sign in. I don't get it, how can I match the user with the subscription if I don't know who the user is? Originally I had this button visible all the time and clicking on it would let the app know if the signed in user had the subscription or not. I don't know how else to achieve this. If user is not signed in, how do you know if they have subscription or not?